# Multiple datepicker in a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

Edit : Thanks for all the tips, I found the culprit it was a typo in PHP script which is longer than what I linked. And now I'm updating my code to make it less messy :)

Hi I'm new to datepicker.

I have two datepicker in my form. But when I send it and I try to do $_POST only the $_POST['date2'] return something, $_POST['date1'] is NULL.

$_POST["datepicker1"] and $_POST["datepicker2"] return null too

HTML head

```
  <script>
 $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
    });
  </script>
```

HTML body

```
<form class="form-inline" action="somewhere.php" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date1">Date 1:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker1" name="date1" id="datepicker1" placeholder="Date">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="date2">Date 2:</label>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker2" name="date2" id="datepicker2" placeholder="Date">

</div>

<button type="submit" name="button2" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP Script

```
<p>Date: <?php echo $_SESSION["date"]; ?><br>
Datepicker 1: <?php echo $__POST["datepicker1"]; ?><br>
Date 1: <?php echo $_SESSION["date1"]; ?></br>
Datepicker 2: <?php echo $_POST["datepicker2"]; ?><br>
Date 2: <?php echo $_SESSION["date2"]; ?><br></p>
```

Comment: post your php script

Comment: YES, post your php script, there is no issue in this code.

Comment: what @rahul means is that your `for` attributes should match the target ID, not the NAME. - anyways that's not the main issue

Comment: use name $_POST["date1"]

Comment: check if there are any other elements with same name

Comment: $_POST["datepicker1"] and $_POST["datepicker2"] THIS WILL return null only...
You should use $_POST['name-of-input-box']. you did this and actually issue is different,

Comment: @Romain have you selected date's from calendar?

Comment: As suspected the issue is from your php script.

Comment: use name <?php  echo $_POST["date1"];  echo  $_POST["date2"];  ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, the issue is from your php script.
Change your php script to:

```
<p>
Datepicker 1: <?php echo $_POST["date1"]; ?><br>
Datepicker 2: <?php echo $_POST["date2"]; ?><br></p>
```

When getting the input values from your html form in php, use the `name` attribute and not the id.

Alternatively, add this

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);//this would display all values from your html form. including keys and values. Remember $_POST returns associative array
?>
```

With regards to your javascript datepicker, as an improvement, you can use one class and loop through it instead of using multiple id's.

Change the class of your datepicker to `datepick`

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
          $('.datepick').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); 
     }); 
        </script>
```

Make sure each input has its own individual id

Comment: i think no need each function here

Comment: @romain Sanitization! :) `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'date1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` - that's some string that comes from the *View*, not from your own b-e logic, so sanitize!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan . This is just to solve OP's problem concerning the null results. OP would have to sanitize variables and so fort. Remember we are just echoing the variables. Nothing more was provided by OP